# Grep for multiple patterns over multiple files

Tags: grep

I've been googling around, and I can't find the answer I'm looking for.

Say I have a file, `text1.txt`, in directory `mydir` whose contents are:

```
one
two
```

and another called `text2.txt`, also in `mydir`, whose contents are:

```
two
three
four
```

I'm trying to get a list of files (for a given directory) which contain all (not any) patterns I search for.  In the example I provided, I'm looking for output somewhere along the lines of:

```
./text1.txt
```

or

```
./text1.txt:one
./text1.txt:two
```

The only things I've been able to find are concerning matching any patterns in a file, or matching multiple patterns in a single file (which I tried extending to a whole directory, but received grep usage errors).

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit-Things I've tried

```
grep "pattern1" < ./* | grep "pattern2" ./*
```

"ambiguous redirect"

```
grep 'pattern1'|'pattern2' ./*
```

returns files that match either pattern

Comment: What was the usage error message? And what was the command you tried?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way could be like this:

```
find . | xargs grep 'pattern1' -sl | xargs grep 'pattern2' -sl
```

Comment: or the alternate of this like: `grep -rl 'pattern1' | xargs grep 'pattern2' -l`

Comment: `grep -rlZ 'pattern1' | xargs --null grep 'pattern2' -l` to be extra safe about file names.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you need (you can add easily more patterns)

```
grep -EH 'pattern1|pattern2' mydir
```

Comment: that's an or, OP wants an and

Answer (score 2):

To refine brain's answer:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'pattern1' -slZ | xargs -0 grep 'pattern2' -sl
```

This will keep grep from trying to search directories, and can properly handle filenames with spaces, if you pass the -Z flag to grep for all but the last pattern and pass -0 to xargs.