# Recursively find files that contain all the given patterns

Tags: bash, grep, find, exec

I have a directory **/Folder1/Folder2** with multiple projects with multiple files.
Some files have the extension ".ext".

Some ".ext" files have "Word1", another ".ext" files have "Word2" and other have "Word3".

I want to know how to find only ".ext" files containing "Word1" **AND** "Word2" **AND** "Word3" (the **three** words) in my directory Recursively...

With **find** command its possible to filter the files.

```
find /Folder1/Folder2  -iname "*.ext" -exec grep -i 'Word1' {} \;
```

With **grep**

```
grep -inR "Word1" --include \*.ext /Folder1/Folder2 
grep -inR "Word2" --include \*.ext /Folder1/Folder2
grep -inR "Word3" --include \*.ext /Folder1/Folder2
```

But, How Can use combined **grep** command?

The next [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422743/grep-for-multiple-patterns-over-multiple-files) doesn't work for me.

```
find /Folder1/Folder2 -iname "*.eXt" | xargs grep 'Word1' -sl | xargs grep 'Word2' -sl| xargs grep 'Word3' -sl
```

**EDIT1**

I found & I was testing this:

```
find /Folder1/Folder2 -iname "*.ext" -exec grep -qi 'Word1' {} \; -exec grep -qi 'Word2' {} \; -print
find /Users/joseluisbz/Google\ Drive/Developer/a\ TableCellRenderer  -iname "*.java" -exec grep -qi 'UI' {} \; -exec grep -qi 'Slider' {} \; -print
```

THE RESULTS

```
joseluisbz-MacBook:~ joseluisbz$ find /Users/joseluisbz/Google\ Drive/Developer/a\ TableCellRenderer  -iname "*.java" -exec grep -qi 'UI' {} \; -exec grep -qi 'Slider' {} \; -print
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/ChangeLafAtRuntineDemo.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/ChangeLafAtRuntineDemo.new.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/ChangeLafAtRuntineDemoOld.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/ColorThumbJSlider.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/JFr_SplitPaneMotif.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/JLayeredPaneJSliderLAF.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/JSliderLAF.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/JSliderTableExample.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/RedGreenSliderUI.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/TestMultiSlider.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/TestSliderLayeredPane.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/UIManagerDefaults.java
```

Checking another method!

```
$ while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do     grep -q 'UI' "$file" &&      grep -q 'Slider' "$file";     echo "$file"; done < <(find /Users/joseluisbz/Google\ Drive/Developer/a\ TableCellRenderer -iname '*.java' -print0)
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/AnotherPanelInTable.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/AnotherSeparatorSample.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/AutoCompleteComboBox.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/ButtonGroupExample.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/ChangeLafAtRuntineDemo.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/ChangeLafAtRuntineDemo.new.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/ChangeLafAtRuntineDemo.oldWorking.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/ChangeLafAtRuntineDemoOld.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/ClientServerShort.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/ClientServerTCP.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/ColorComboBoxEditor.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/ColorComboBoxEditorRendererDemo.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/ColorEditor.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/ColorRenderer.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/ColorThumbJSlider.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/ComboBoxCustomScroller.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/CustomImageButton.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/CustomJComboBox/src/net/codejava/swing/combobox/CountryComboBox.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/CustomJComboBox/src/net/codejava/swing/combobox/CountryItemEditor.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/CustomJComboBox/src/net/codejava/swing/combobox/CountryItemRenderer.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/CustomJComboBox/src/net/codejava/swing/combobox/CustomComboBoxTester.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/CustomRendererEditorTableExample.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/DecimalSpinner.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/EjemploJLayeredPane.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/FloatSlider.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/JA_JButton/src/JF_Test.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/JButtonTableExample.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/JFr_SplitPaneMotif.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/JInteractiveTableExample.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/JLayeredPaneJSliderLAF.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/JPopupMenuTest.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/JRadioButtonTableExample.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/JSliderLAF.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/JSliderTableExample.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/JSpinnerTableExample.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/JTabbedText.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/LAFJButton.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/LayeredPaneDemo.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/LayeredPaneDemo2.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/LayeredPaneLayout.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/ListDemo.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/NullPointerExceptionSynthTableUI.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/OverlapLayout.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/PopupJOptionPane.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/RedGreenSliderUI.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/SeparatorExample.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/SimpleLayers.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/SliderSample.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/TableDialogEditDemo.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/TableJButtonSelfWork.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/TableTestCheckBox.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/TableWithPanelContainerOfSpinnerAndRadioButton.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/TableWithPanelContainerOfSpinnerAndRadioButton.new.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/TestComboScroll.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/TestMultiSlider.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/TestSliderLayeredPane.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/TransparentBackgroundSlider.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/TransparentSlider.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/UIManagerDefaults.java
/Users/joseluisbz/Google Drive/Developer/a TableCellRenderer/UsingJLayeredPane.java
joseluisbz-MacBook:~ joseluisbz$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `find` command to find all `*.ext` file and then use `grep` commands to search 3 words:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
    grep -q 'Word1' "$file" && 
    grep -q 'Word2' "$file" &&
    grep -q 'Word3' "$file" &&
    echo "$file"
done < <(find /Folder1/Folder2 -iname '*.ext' -print0)
```

Answer (score 0):

> how find only ".ext" files containing "Word1" AND "Word2" AND "Word3"
>   (the three words) in my directory recursively

***find*** + ***awk*** "hack":

```
find /Folder1/Folder2 -iname "*.ext" | xargs awk -v RS= '$0~/Word1/ && $0~/Word2/ && $0~/Word3/{print FILENAME}'
```

---

- `-v RS=` - considers each file contents as a single line
- `'$0~/Word1/ && $0~/Word2/ && $0~/Word3/{print FILENAME}` - will print only file names which contain ALL three words